# Not able to SSH to AWS EC2 instance from personal Windows 10 PC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have created AWS EC2 instance and trying to SSH to EC2 from my personal Windows 10 PC. I have taken below steps for SSH.

a) Configured Putty and attached .ppk file to Putty profile
b) Added Global IP address(0.0.0.0/0) to SSH in EC2 Security Group
c) Added Port 22 to person PC firewall rule (Inbound/Outbound) rules

Even after above configuration, I am not able to connect to AWS EC2 through Putty.I tried to telnet from CMD as telnet  22 but its giving error as 'Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: Connect failed'.

I am not able to figure out the issue. Please suggest.

Comment: My guess is that your PPK file has some problem.  Are you sure that followed _exactly_ the steps given in the AWS [documentation for connecting to PuTTY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html) for connecting to EC2?

Comment: Yes, I have followed all steps for Putty configuration. I am not sure whether Port 22 on my personal PC is opened because when I run the command 'netstat -an | find "22" | find "LISTENING"  on CMD, It does not show for port 22. Is there any way to verify Port 22 on my windows 10 pc is opened?

Comment: Usually the Win firewall is not blocking outbound traffic, so no reason to do anything about it (if you allow traffic explicitly, it won't be listening automatically). If you use wrong/no key, you will at least connect, but unable to login. Check that you are not using some proxy (common in schools and companies)